# Double confluent Heun function limit, $\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} w(\alpha, q, \gamma, \delta, i z) \rightarrow ?$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my calculations the double confluent Heun differential equation pops up, namely
$$
{\displaystyle {\frac {d^{2}w}{dz^{2}}}+\left[{\frac {\delta }{z^{2}}}+{\frac {\gamma }{z}}+1\right]{\frac {dw}{dz}}+{\frac {\alpha z-q}{z^{2}}}w=0}.
$$
Is there some asymptotic expansion known for a purely imaginary argument, i.e.
$$
\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} w(iz) \rightarrow ?
$$